# Create bytebuffer like object in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, bytebuffer

I need to create a Bytebuffer like object in Ruby. Here is my example in JAVA

```
int ADD_BYTES_FOR_MSG_LENGTH = 4;

Integer messageBodySize = new Integer(messageBody.getBytes().length);
byte[] messageHeader = ByteBuffer.allocate(ADD_BYTES_FOR_MSG_LENGTH).putInt(messageBodySize).array();

messageToSend = new byte[messageHeader.length + messageBodySize];

System.arraycopy(messageHeader, 0, messageToSend, 0, messageHeader.length);
System.arraycopy(messageBody.getBytes(), 0, messageToSend, messageHeader.length, messageBodySize);
```

I create a message starting with 4 bytes where is located size of the message body part, and then the actual message. I have no idea how to do this in Ruby, so please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this for [Steam Condenser](http://koraktor.de/steam-condenser) using an extended version of `StringIO`.

Although I don't use any `put*` methods, these could be easily implemented like for example:

```
class StringIO

  def put_int(i)
    write [i].pack('v')
  end

end
```

You may have a look at the [code](https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser/blob/master/ruby/lib/core_ext/stringio.rb), the [documentation of the original class](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/stringio/1.9.2/StringIO) and [my extensions](http://rubydoc.info/gems/steam-condenser/0.14.0/StringIO).

Comment: I guess you should use `write` instead of `puts` there?

Comment: Thanks for help, but now I'm stuck again... when I do `write [i].pack('L')` (unsigned 32 bit integer) the StringIO object is allocating 5 bytes (method size is returning 5). I need to write this int on 4 bytes only (like in my java example). Could you give me a hint how to handle it?

Comment: @Neuro: Are you using `write` or `puts`? `puts` will append a newline and give you an extra byte, `write` won't. There's also `syswrite` which might match your desired semantics better.

Comment: Yes! Stupid me. Classic copy-paste error. But unfortunately something is not working :/ I do `put_int(size_of_msg)` and then `write(msg)` on the StringIO object and I send it through the socket but in java side app I don't get expected message :/

Comment: I got it! I did it by `write [i].pack('N')` for unpack in network byte order :) And i wrote to the socket by `stringioobj.string` method. Many thanks for all of you for help, this problem was pain in my ass for almost a week :)

Comment: You're right, `puts` adds a `\n` at the end of the data. Just like `Kernel#puts` and other `IO#puts` do.